# Switching between specialization and overloading

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, overloading

from the code below, I get the following output:

> Call member_function
>
> Derived member function
>
> Call template_function
>
> template function
>
> Derived member function

As expected, the specialization of template_function is not called here because derived is of type Base*, but the correct version of member_function is called.

However, sometimes, it may be useful to call not-member functions in template functions.

Does exist a way to ensure that the specialized version of the template function will be called when dynamic instances of Derived class are declared as being of type Base*?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

// Base and Derived classes

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void member_function() const
        { std::cout << "Base member function" << std::endl; };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void member_function() const
        { std::cout << "Derived member function" << std::endl;};
};


// Functions

template<typename T>
void template_function(T const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "template function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}

template<>
void template_function(Derived const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}


// Main

int main ()
{
    Base * derived = new Derived();;

    std::cout << "Call member_function" << std::endl;
    derived->member_function();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Call template_function" << std::endl;
    template_function(*derived);

}
```

Comment: Look at [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you Jarrod. Il will look at the visitor pattern.

Comment: Barry, I would like to know if it is possible to implicitly call template_function<Derived>(x) when x is of type Base*: Base* x = new Derived();

Comment: @Aleph No, a `Base*` is not a `Derived*` (and definitely not a `Derived`)

Comment: Sure, you're right. I made a mistake in my comment: template_function<Derived>(*x).

Comment: And of course I know a Base* is not a Derived*. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two templates `template_function` that you `enable_if` on `std::base_of<T, Derived>`, like this

```
// Functions
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_base_of<T, Derived>::value>* = nullptr>
void template_function(T const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "template function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, Derived>::value>* = nullptr>
void template_function(T const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}


// Main

int main ()
{
    Base const * base = new Base();
    Base const * derived = new Derived();

    std::cout << "Call member_function" << std::endl;
    base->member_function();
    derived->member_function();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Call template_function" << std::endl;
    template_function(*base);
    template_function(*derived);

}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77b49f45fed57f98).

Alternatively, and much simpler, you can simply add a `template_function(Base const&)` overload

```
// Functions
template<typename T>
void template_function(T const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "template function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}

void template_function(Base const & arg)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized function" << std::endl;
    arg.member_function();
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1735fdeef9b7b172)